# Running the unit Tests which are using Azure APIs and other infrastructure in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops

I would like to know, how we can run Unit Tests which use azure related infra and apis like Keyvault, service fabric, azure active directory.
When we try to execute those tests using common Test Tasks in the Build Pipeline, it fails to connect.
So we end up mocking those tests, but what if i don't want to mock those tests. And would like to see if there is an option to run it how it runs in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you show what error messages you get running those tests without mocks?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, actually there comes no error, but if my Unit Test Method contains a call to any azure api, like resolving keyvault values ( a very basic eg) the Test case execution never completes, the Build Pipeline task keeps running, forever. What i learned from folks here in microsoft is the Azure DevOps doesn't support direct execution of test cases which invoke keyvault, redis apis etc.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Test task does not define any arguments for accepting Service connections.

If you want to invoke keyvault, you could try to use below ways:

- [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) task: Can be used to fetch all or a subset of secrets from the vault, and set them as variables that can be used in subsequent tasks of a pipeline.
- [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault): Link an existing Azure key vault to a variable group and map selective vault secrets to the variable group.

Kindly check below blogs for detail ways:

- [Using Azure Key Vault Secrets from your Azure DevOps pipelines](https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/)
- [Using Secrets in Azure Pipelines](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/devops/1507/azure-key-vault-secrets-pipelines)